# NSIS - How to set an environment variable in system variable

Tags: environment-variables, nsis

I want to set the environment variable in system variable path for my application. How can I set that using nsis?

For example: `C:\Program Files\Sample\bin`, I want to set this path in System variable.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to do this. I assume you want to set this permanently and not just for the installer

You could use ns::Exec or ExecWait to run setx as mentioned by the other answer. The downside to this is that setx only comes with Windows Vista or later. Windows XP users would not have their path set. The SET command is for the process only and would not permanently set the path.

You could use ReadEnvString to read the current path, format it how you wanted, and then output it back out with WriteRegExpandStr. See http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Setting_Environment_Variables. The downside to this is you have to do all your formatting of the path yourself, and you have to duplicate work that's already been done for you in the EnvVarUpdate function - mentioned below...

The method I use is the EnvVarUpdate function. You can find the code for this function here; [http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Environmental_Variables:_append,_prepend,_and_remove_entries](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Environmental_Variables%3a_append,_prepend,_and_remove_entries)

Using this function with your example path it would be;

```
${EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "A" "HKLM" "C:\Program Files\Sample\bin" ; appends to the system path

${EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "A" "HKCU" "C:\Program Files\Sample\bin" ; appends to the user path
```

This allows you to choose to append or prepend, and it allows you to remove what you added in your uninstaller.

Note that NSIS with the default compiled binaries has a maximum string length of 1024 characters. If the path is longer than that, you can corrupt it if you don't apply the patch listed in the above link.  The preferred solution would be to download the binary of makensis which has the string length set to 8192 characters, or compile the source yourself and set a longer string length.  You can find more info here; http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set` to add/change an environment variable or you could use `setx` to set one permanently (as if you added it via computer properties).

here's the documentation for [setx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754250%28v=ws.10%29)

Comment: I don't see any obvious way to use `setx` to add a path component to the `PATH` variable. Though OP said set, the requirement is almost certainly for `C:\Program Files\Sample\bin` to be *added* to the search path, not to be the entire search path.

Comment: How about `setx PATH %PATH%;C:\Program Files\Sample\bin`

Comment: That relies on `cmd.exe` to substitute `%PATH%`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

1. For simple variables holding only one value or one directory see
   http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Setting_Environment_Variables#Exisiting_Variables
2. For variables that hold path-lists see
   http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Environmental_Variables:_append%2C_prepend%2C_and_remove_entries#Function_Code

However the second solution requires inclusion of a .nsh-file and it is not clear how to completely reset a variable. It rather has the functionality to remove, append or prepend to a semicolon-seperated list of entries (such as the PATH-Variable).